# Django using more than one forms in one page from same model

Tags: django, forms

I want to use more than one forms in the same page from the same model.

Ok, lets take it easy.

I have Social modules that have 3 attributes (network, url and image) charfield.
I've added 4 values in Social database (Facebbok, Twitter, Youtube, Pinterest)

In the settings view (settings.html) i want to have all 4 forms (for Facebook, Twitter etc.) to edit them.

Something like that:

Facebook: text input (that contains the current facebook url)

Youtube: text input (that contains the current youtube url)

etc.

So when i go to settings.html i can change, update social url for all networks.

I have something like this for General Settings module (that have 3 fields, Title, Slug, Description and 1 attribute cuz the website have 1 title, 1 slug and 1 description). For this one is pretty simple i can use get_object_or_404 because Settings module have just 1 value and i can select it.. but the problem is Social Module have more values and i want to have on my page all forms from them so i can edit how ever i want.

**views.py**

```
def settings(request):
sidebar_items = Sidebar.objects.order_by('position')
social_items = Social.objects.order_by('network')
settings = get_object_or_404(Settings, pk = 1)
if request.method == "POST":
    form_settings = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance = settings)
    if form_settings.is_valid():
        settings = form_settings.save(commit = False)
        settings.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/settings')
else:
    form_settings = SettingsForm(instance = settings)

context = {'sidebar_items' : sidebar_items, 'form_settings' : form_settings, 'social_items' : social_items}
return render(request, 'dashboard/settings.html', context)
```

Comment: What's stopping you from adding more forms to your context?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't care how many forms you want to initialize in your view. If they're for the same model, you can use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/). Otherwise, you can initialize and create objects however you want.

Example:

```
def your_view(request):

    social_items = Social.objects.order_by('network')
    forms = []
    for index, social_item in enumerate(social_items):
        forms.append(SocialForm(request.POST or None, instance=social_item,
            prefix="form_{}".format(index)))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for form in forms:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

        # do whatever next

    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'forms': forms})
```

You don't need three separate form tags in your template. You can submit all of the data in one post. Django will try to hydrate an instance of each model from the POST data, and return any errors if that fails.

In your template, you'll need to iterate over the form instances:

```
# some-template.html

<form action="." method="post" enctype="x-www-form-urlencoded">
    {% for form in forms %}
    <ol>
        <li>
            {{ form.network }}
            {{ form.network.errors }}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ form.url }}
            {{ form.url.errors }}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ form.image }}
            {{ form.image.errors }}
        </li>
    </ol>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is not what i want. In Social module i have 2 values: Facebook and Twitter. In settings view (settings.html) i want to have facebook forms and twitter forms to edit them.. for one value i can use get_object_or_404 and it simple, but i have 3-4 values in my database

Comment: Define "values". Are you talking about instances of models? Do you have a Facebook model and a Twitter model? I think you need to add more information to your question.

Comment: Right, so like I mentioned, you can use a formset to edit those, or as I demonstrated, you can pass in the individual `social` instances, all to the same form class if you want.

Comment: I've updated the code sample to show how you can initialize multiple forms from your `Social` instances.

Comment: Ok.. but now i have problems with display forms in settings.html.. {% for social in social_items %}
            <div class="field">
                <label for="{{ social.network}}"> {{ social.network }}:</label><br>
                {{ social_form.url }} 
        {% endfor %}

Comment: Right, now you have to iterate over the forms, which are separate from the model instances.

Comment: And how i'm supposed to do that? anyway thanks you a lot for helping a newbie like e :D