# How can i have multiple forms on a django template

Tags: python, django

I am absolutely new to django and python and i have the following question:

I want to have two Forms on a single page. Each form should have a own submit button which triggers a different background process.
I already read that i shoul have one view for each form. But how can i use two views with one template?

( i am currently using Django 1.7)

Comment: You shouldn't have a separate view for each form, I don't know where you read that. A view corresponds to a page; if you have multiple forms on one page, you need to deal with them all in the same view.

Comment: but how can i have multiple forms in one view?

i read e.g. this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022814/django-using-more-than-one-forms-in-one-page-from-same-model

there are the forms displayed in a for-loop.

but then i would only have one submit button. 
And i don't know how to handle the differnt requests from the views

Comment: You can have as many forms as you like. What is preventing you? The submit buttons are not generated as part of the Django form anyway, you need to add them yourself, so you can have as many of those as you want as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why shouldn't form have separate views? Each view could ``reverse(redirect(...))`` to a template it originated on. Instead of one view dealing with a complex conditional flow. I'm django noob, so I'm curious. :)

Comment: @Liliane well if the form is invalid you wouldn't be able to display validation messages in the same place if you did that.

Comment: you can use django formset for this perpose

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have a base template with a "sign up for our newsletter" , or a "login"form on all of our pages. The template page is rendered by one view, but any signups / logins  get processed by their own view.